# form.$invalid is not working for angular ui date picker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

i have two fields  `due date` and a text filed `enter a number`

`due date` which is a date picker ,either we can select date from date picker or

we can set date by entering number in second text field.

`button create` will be enabled if i manually set the date field from date picker but but it is not enabling if i set date picker value by entering text field

can anybody tell me why this is happening.
 this is jsfiddle link [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cpu4euoj/206/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have errors with your date parsing logic,
Change your function to this.

```
$scope.getDueDate = function() {
    var  d = parseInt($scope.daysFrom);
    var newDate = moment(new Date()).add(d, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    $scope.AvailableDate = newDate;
}
```